# Unable to parse Podfile.lock error on Pod install/update

Tags: ios, cocoapods, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

Not able to update/ install pods.
Error is 'Unable to parse Podfile.lock file'.
Last pod installed was: pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'
After that the issue started coming.

**Error Log**

```
[!] ERROR: Parsing unable to continue due to parsing error:
contained in the file located at /Users/ios/Documents/Projects/DemoProject4/Podfile.lock
PODS:

!ProtoCompiler (3.0.2):
Protobuf (~> 3.0)
!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin (1.0.2):
!ProtoCompiler (= 3.0.2)
gRPC-ProtoRPC (= 1.0.2)
Alamofire (4.5.1)
BoringSSL (7.0):
BoringSSL/Implementation (= 7.0)
BoringSSL/Interface (= 7.0)
BoringSSL/Implementation (7.0):
BoringSSL/Interface (= 7.0)
BoringSSL/Interface (7.0)
googleapis (0.0.1):
!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin (~> 1.0.0-pre1.1)
googleapis/Messages (= 0.0.1)
googleapis/Services (= 0.0.1)
googleapis/Messages (0.0.1):
!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin (~> 1.0.0-pre1.1)
Protobuf
googleapis/Services (0.0.1):
!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin (~> 1.0.0-pre1.1)
googleapis/Messages
gRPC-ProtoRPC
gRPC (1.0.2):
gRPC-Core (= 1.0.2)
gRPC-RxLibrary (= 1.0.2)
gRPC-Core (1.0.2):
gRPC-Core/Implementation (= 1.0.2)
gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.0.2)
gRPC-Core/Implementation (1.0.2):
BoringSSL (~> 7.0)
gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.0.2)
gRPC-Core/Interface (1.0.2)
gRPC-ProtoRPC (1.0.2):
gRPC (= 1.0.2)
gRPC-RxLibrary (= 1.0.2)
Protobuf (~> 3.0)
gRPC-RxLibrary (1.0.2)
Protobuf (3.5.0)
DEPENDENCIES:

Alamofire
googleapis (from .)
EXTERNAL SOURCES:
googleapis:
:path: .

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
!ProtoCompiler: cfad9cbe5299a4923b1c3c8f150818c91efd0b6d
!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin: ee00d28bb35b26e2657f239833b8f2aa66724f96
Alamofire: 2d95912bf4c34f164fdfc335872e8c312acaea4a
BoringSSL: 50035b9d9eeff5529587311782fc57c00ebf13ae
googleapis: daa20dca7a0097c6c3316fdfd888e0ba1b7c8921
gRPC: dd3a91e0fb770b9fc4f43d1292fb19f2a2e04158
gRPC-Core: cc4a7613190ff0bc60a0c1e702ef07cd3f868ae6
gRPC-ProtoRPC: 11533510522a5e9627883a597a796cfe6bef05f3
gRPC-RxLibrary: 02cc70b76bc0c5bc622ba27595cca2598d9fe528
Protobuf: 8a9838fba8dae3389230e1b7f8c104aa32389c03

PODFILE CHECKSUM: bba8f9c22e10518c7ea6f79ab0fb8177c097b5f5

COCOAPODS: 1.4.0.beta.2
```

How to resolve the error. Even if I have to remove the googleapis pod, I will do it. But removing it from podfile and hit pod-install command is not working, as pod-intsall/pod-update commands always yields this error.

[My Demo Project downloadable link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d13g7alb9k7wmou/DemoProj6.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

This is a CocoaPods [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6955) that has been fixed in 1.4.0.

The workaround is to remove Podfile.lock before `pod install` or `pod update`.

Comment: Mine is showing:   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.4.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods.rb .  but still same issue. The issue persists even if I remove podfile.lock before pod_install. The reason is, there is Manifest.lock file also. Shall I remove that too ?